# aData is undefined using FormOnlyData in datatables

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I'm using JQuery DataTables I'm getting `TypeError: aData is undefined` following is my JS code:

```
$('#brands').DataTable({
      dom: "Bfrtip",
      serverside: true,
      ajax: "getCompanies",
      columns: [
          {data: "name"},
          {data: "last_name"},
          {data: "gender"},
          {data: "city"},
      ],
      select: true,
 });
```

This is my JSON reponse

```
{
  "data": [{
    "DT_RowId": "row_1",
    "id": 1,
    "company_id": 1,
    "name": "Saeed",
    "last_name": "last_name",
    "email": "uandsaeed
@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2y$10$P4d496V0FPNF7DtcOZBFVeNBe5DYpCvR9nSBtoZs9.iI0DgzisuIW",
    "phone_no": "02123456744",
    "address": "fsd road abk",
    "skype_id": "",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "gender": "",
    "shoe_size": null,
    "user_type": "CompanyAdmin",
    "user_image": null,
    "remember_token": "j2eu3QeYfql1pdbgcrypYnErAHYBdlyxmOCzMF3rT1XQtpV48oYNwEtVHwrk",
    "created_at": "2016-07-15 20:02:55",
    "updated_at": "2016-07-29 10:30:27",
    "deleted_at": null
  }, {
    "DT_RowId": "row_3",
    "id": 3,
    "company_id": 2,
    "name": "Saeed nm",
    "last_name": "",
    "email": "saeed@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2y$10$u2qDYiBW2mPGH6IL0VsPzO
\/YlUFI3QiizUgBPWPAI842r58ytsa..",
    "phone_no": "",
    "address": "",
    "skype_id": "",
    "city": "",
    "gender": "Male",
    "shoe_size": null,
    "user_type": "CompanyAdmin",
    "user_image": null,
    "remember_token": "H4P7H4Gv5XMjFPjjEDEtrsxp93MMbb4Vt9vut7vaLkJIXemmeWgbkTjzgarM",
    "created_at": "2016-07-15 20:22:52",
    "updated_at": "2016-07-19 10:06:23",
    "deleted_at": null
  }, {
    "DT_RowId": "row_4",
    "id": 4,
    "company_id": 3,
    "name": "company",
    "last_name": "last_name",
    "email": "company@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2y$10$8rpLCC7mquu2BNoeJVi6OeeA7p9KlTP3QRUc3B\/\/TIX5Vqx0yP7Nm",
    "phone_no": "098765433456",
    "address": "Iqbal Town, Lahore, Punjab, Pakistan",
    "skype_id": "",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "gender": "",
    "shoe_size": null,
    "user_type": "CompanyAdmin",
    "user_image": null,
    "remember_token": null,
    "created_at": "2016-07-27 11:55:31",
    "updated_at": "2016-07-27 11:55:31",
    "deleted_at": null
  }],
  "options": [],
  "files": []
}
```

I'm following this as reference [data tables with Form Only Data](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/formOnlyData.html)

Comment: What have you tried so far, out of the numerous things that come up when you google the error?

Comment: This is as per documentation and there is no specific help for this data table which is with form specifically. if you can refer me to such a link i will gladly look into it, other data table examples/templates have numerous help but this is kinda unique.

Answer (score 0):

The doc you linked is for DataTable.Editor, a for-sale addition to the free DataTable plugin.  You'll notice that the example that you're working with starts with this:

```
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
```

whereas the code you've posted starts with this:

```
$('#brands').DataTable({
```

The doc you're working with is a way to specify a table full of editable values on a form, which isn't part of the DataTable capabilities.  The error you're getting is because you have failed to specify a data source, which is required when you call the `DataTable()` function.

Comment: if you read the code mentioned above , i am actually not implementing the editor functionality, so other then that its just a normal DataTable.

Comment: Well, yes. And if you read the documentation mentioned above, that you say you are "following", you'll see that the object in the doc is not just a normal DataTable, so you aren't really following it. That's my point.  Again, you'll need to research where you're going wrong.  [This basic explanation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/) might be a good thing to start with.  Then, you need to troubleshoot your `getCompanies` and make sure it's returning the JSON, and go from there.